# Best way to parse/query heterogenous CSV data in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large amount of log data that is semi-structured as CSV data. However, each individual row's columns are dependent on what type of row it is, indicated by a particular column.

Example data:

```
8/01/2018, person, 1, Bob, Loblaw 32
8/01/2018, person, 2, Roger, McRoger, 55
8/03/2018, dog, Bella,  9, 1
8/05/2018, person, 3, Charlie, McCharles, 23
8/07/2018, dog, Scout, 5, 3
```

This particular example shows a semi-structured file with two schemas interspersed, roughly equating to these case classes:

```
case class Person(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)
case class Dog(name: String, age: Int, ownerId: Int)
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to parse these interspersed data via Spark efficiently so that I can query the dataset, potentially joining between the various row types.

I can load CSV data into a structured schema when all rows are the same, but the heterogenous nature of the rows in these files is stumping me. I've considered that I may be able to use Spark to read the data as text to start with and then do some kind of groupBy operation on the "type" column, at which point I could parse each group individually, but I've not been able to formulate code to do so as the semantics of DataFrames appear to be quite different than a standard Scala collection, eg: groupBy in Spark is not equivalent to a Scala collection groupBy, so far as I can tell.

I realize I could process these files with some sort of ETL prior to using Spark to normalize the data, but it just seems like it should be possible to skip that step and let Spark query the data as-is. Am I just fundamentally on the wrong path?

Comment: You can load your data first into a RDD first. Transform the loaded RDD using split in the Map Action. In the resultant RDD, apply a filter to search for 'dog' and assign it to an RDD. Now create a schema and map it to this RDD. This can be repeated for 'person' too. :)

Comment: This means I'd have to traverse the data at least N times, N being the number of row types. Is there a way to split the data and apply the appropriate schemas with a single traversal?

Comment: I think it is not possible in a single traversal. Also, filter() is a parallel operation. So, the search/traversal will be done in node(s). Suppose we have say 100 records and 10 node cluster. Assume that, once the 100 records are loaded into RDD, all 10 nodes get 10 records each. The number of search/traversal will be less.

Comment: Is logging `Person` and `Dog` to separate files an option?

Comment: @Simon Unfortunately these files are provided by a 3rd party and we have no control over them. We could use an ETL process to separate them out, but my gut feeling is that Spark can probably handle that itself given that the data is quite structured despite being interspersed. I'm completely new to Spark, however, and it's been difficult finding much guidance on this topic via google.

Answer (score 2):

```
case class Person(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)
val df=spark.read.csv("..whateverpath.csv")
val p = df.filter(trim($"_c1")==="person").select(trim($"_c2").cast("Int").alias("id"),$"_c3".alias("firstName"),$"_c4".alias("lastName"),trim($"_c5").cast("Int").alias("age")).as[Person]
```

and similarly for the Dog case class (note that this would break if the first row will be shorter - in which case you want to specify a schema).
To prevent reading the files twice, you can cache `df.cache()` before you process it

Answer (score 1):

At large scales, data is often denormalized (nested structures, type mismatches, extra/missing fields, etc). Trying to force-normalize semi-structured data into DataFrames can be cumbersome especially with billions of records.

I suggest looking into the open-source [Rumble](http://rumbledb.org) engine, which is an extra layer on top of Spark. It was specifically designed for heterogeneous data scenarios like this one (Disclaimer: I am part of the team).

For example, it is possible to go through the document, and convert it to a mixed sequence of JSON objects (which do not have to respect a schema) that can be queried at will. The language is JSONiq:

```
let $my-heterogeneous-list :=
  (: first we convert each CSV line to a JSON object, switching on person/dog :)
  for $i in text-file("/path/to/heterogeneous-csv.txt")
  let $j := tokenize($i, ", ")
  let $person := $j[2] eq "person"
  return if($person)
       then {
         "kind" : "person",
         "date" : $j[1],
         "id" : $j[3],
         "first" : $j[4],
         "last" : $j[5],
         "age" : $j[6]
       } else {
         "kind" : "dog",
         "date" : $j[1],
         "name" : $j[3],
         "age" : $j[4],
         "owner" : $j[5]
       }
(: now we can query and re-arrange :)
return
  for $dog in $my-heterogeneous-list[$$.kind eq "dog"]
  return {|
      project($dog, ("date", "name")), 
      { "owner" : $my-heterogeneous-list[$$.id eq $dog.owner] }
  |}
```

Which returns a list of dogs with their nested owners (denormalized):

```
{ 
  "date" : "8\/03\/2018",
  "name" : "Bella",
  "owner" : { 
    "kind" : "person", 
    "date" : "8\/01\/2018", 
    "id" : "1", 
    "first" : "Bob", 
    "last" : "Loblaw", 
    "age" : "32" 
  } 
}
{
  "date" : "8\/07\/2018",
  "name" : "Scout",
  "owner" : {
    "kind" : "person",
    "date" : "8\/05\/2018",
    "id" : "3",
    "first" : "Charlie",
    "last" : "McCharles",
    "age" : "23"
  } 
}
```